# How to get FFmpeg to make an exact copy of a video?

Tags: ffmpeg

I was playing around with FFmpeg, trying to embed a tag into an mp4 file and remove it later and get back to the original file, when I noticed that the files seemed to be different. Trying to isolate the issue, I tried to do a simple passthrough copy like so:

```
ffmpeg -i file1.mp4 -codec copy file2.mp4
```

The md5 sums of both files are different. Am I missing any options/flags to make an exact replica of file1?

Comment: Why would you expect the MD5 sums to be the same?  FFmpeg is repackaging the original video.  The stream contents will be identical, but undoubtedly with differences in the containers.  Even if you used the same muxer, there are different default options, and output differences between versions.  If you want the same file, just copy the file.

Comment: Look into the streamhash muxer. If the stream syntax was valid in the source, then streamhash results should be identical in the output.